# Retrieving parameter values through reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to come up with a design for a method that takes another method as a parameter and retrieves the parameter values of the method passed. How can this be done? I've tried using `java.lang.reflect.*` but can't seem to find an API that supports this.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943612/java-how-to-get-arguments-passed-to-method-that-called-this-method

Comment: and this is my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73263342/5050750

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't really get the values passed as parameters like this.

You can make your own [`Proxy`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) and from there capture parameters before calling the right method. Or with [aspect](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) you could get the parameters value directly when the method is called.

Answer (score -1):

Method.getParameterTypes

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getParameterTypes%28%29

Comment: It's isn't the parameters values, it's parameters types.