# How to get arguments passed to method that called this method?

Tags: java, debugging, arguments, stack-trace

In Java, it is possible to get the class and method that called the current method (the method in which you get the StackTrace).

Can I get the arguments that were passed to the method that called this method?

I need this for debugging purposes.

Eg:

```
baseClass {
   initialFunc(input) {
       var modifiedInput = input + " I modified you";
       otherClass.doSomething(modifiedInput);
   }
}

otherClass {
    doSomething(input)  {
         //GET THE ARGUMENTS PASSED TO THE METHOD OF THE CLASS THAT CALLED THIS METHOD
    }
}
```

Can one get this information from the stacktrace, or are there other means?

*(Note that I need to be able to do this in runtime and cannot actually change the source of baseClass, this is going to be a feature of my debugging class that does not know the source beforehand)*

Comment: you can if you attach a debugger, otherwise - no. The parameters might be in CPU registers (not on the stack)

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot attach a debugger for my purposes

Comment: Then you're lost, besides ClassLoader and enhancing on-the-fly the class to trap the arguments. (but you'd not ask if you knew how)

Comment: When a debugger can do it, then it must be possible somehow. AFAIK, a debugger doesn't use code instrumentation or alike, since it can be attached to any Java process. No idea how this works, maybe some JMX?

Comment: The debugger has its own API and it's not JMX but you must start java w/ the debugger settings. Technically you can implement the debugger interface, stop the thread, examine the stack frame, etc...

Comment: @bestssss so theoretically it is possible to copy paste the debugger API into my own debugging library?

Comment: @Tom, copy/paste  - hardly, eclipse has an implementation of (the API is socket based). Which part of 'starting w/ the debgger settings' is unclear? I told that in my very 1st comment. Anaways, to recap: you have the options: a) start w/ a debugger settings and implement and interface, hopefully you can debugger from the same process; b) modify the JVM; c) load the classes and enhance them on-the-fly to store their arguments and clean on exit, it will slow down the execution significantly.

Comment: @bestsss, what class would you extend in the JDK to modifiy the JVM (option b)? How would you enhance the classes on the fly (option c) to store their arguments?

Comment: @Tom, still i am in the haze, how will you call your OWN classes within unmodified source code? The call illustrated above in your question cannot happen unless you force it to...

Comment: @Tom, enhancing on the fly will be around at least 3k-4k lines of code, modifying the VM - not extending, you need to hack the hotspot (it's in C)

Comment: @bestsss, of course the methods are called by an application. I however do not wish to modifiy the source of this application in order to see the arguments of the caller (it's a temporary debug). I cannot attach a debugger either. So I am interested in option b and c. For option b, can I not just find a "Method" class in the JDK source, modify that and rebuild the JDK? (I am talking about the high level .java files source, not the C source)

Comment: @Tom, I never mentioned JDK, and if you have full control over the running environment I see no reason to skip the debugger as the most natural choice.

Comment: @bestsss, I cannot attach a debugger (I have my reasons). Simply redistributing a modified JDK is more suitable for my needs. Is there no class in the JDK that each method inherits?

Comment: @bestsss, this lead me to a follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945358/java-do-methods-inherit-a-jre-super-class-like-classes-inherit-object - I accepted this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible using the standard Java API.

What you could do is to use AspectJ, place a point-cut at the calling method, save the arguments, place a point-cut at the called method and pass on the arguments.

Another option (slightly more advanced) is to use a custom, bytecode-rewriting, class loader that saves the original arguments, and passes them on as extra arguments to the next method. This would probably take a day or two to implement. Suitable frameworks are [BCEL](http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/) or [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/).

Comment: The AspectJ approach would force me to change the source before runtime, so it is not an option. About the other option, can I make a JRE extention that updates whatever class every Method uses? If so, what class are methods/functions using in the JRE?

Comment: Here is an AspectJ example in similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14089562/603516

Answer (score 2):

I think this could be possible, because `input` is out of scope but isn't yet accessible for garbage collection, so the value still exists, but unfortunately I don't believe there is an default API way to access it. This could be maybe possible with a custom implemented NDC (*nested diagnostic context*) for the logging approach.

Comment: Formal parameters are regarded as local varibales, whose content are stored on the stack, and thus never garbage collected.

Comment: it's not necessary to be stored on the stack at all. The method can be inlined and/or the parameters can be in CPU registers (which is what happens w/ the 'hot' code)

Comment: Are you sure there is no way to access it?

Comment: @Tom, if you run w/ debug settings you some other agent, you can do that. Normally you can't.

Comment: @bestsss, I'm talking about the activation-record stack of the jvm.

Comment: @aioobe, but it (the record) might not exist even, if the code is inlined.

Comment: I'm not talking about anything JVM-specific. I'm referring to the Java Language Specification.

Comment: @aioobe, if you mean the GC, certainly; but I was talking about obtaining the parameters mostly.

Comment: I'm not saying that it is easy, or even possible. I'm simply saying that the content of the arguments will not be garbage collected. Only objects on the *heap* are garbage collected.

Comment: well, it's not possible w/o modifying the JVM or custom loader to enhance the classes (and that will slow down the performance considerably)

Comment: @codevour, I am not sure how the NDC approach would work. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I needed to get a parameter value has been passed to a method in a certain stack frame to be used later within the execution flow

I used `ThreadLocal` to store it and when I needed it I was able to retrieve it at any point in code as I declared it as `public static`

here is a skeleton example

```
public static final ThreadLocal<SomeType> IMPORTANT_THREAD_LOCAL_FOR_BLA = ThreadLocal.withInitial(whatever);

methodWithImportantParam(SomeType importantValue){
    // save it in the static threadLocal Field
    this.IMPORTANT_THREAD_LOCAL_FOR_BLA.get()=importantValue;// code to set the value
    // continue method logic
}
```

and somewhere in code where you need that value

```
YourClass.IMPORTANT_THREAD_LOCAL_FOR_BLA.get()
```

but make sure the execution flow that you set the value then you retrieve it

hope my answer add something valuable to this question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you'd ever want to do this in Java?

The only way I can think of is to create a custom wrapper object for the passed string, thus sending the reference to the wrapper instead of a new string each time.
I'd advice against it, though, since it clutters your original code, and makes it even more error prone.

Might this problem not be solved using a debugger, like the one built into eclipse, to inspect your state?

Answer (score -4):

You can get name of caller method and its class, but you have to add some code in current method:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    call();
}

private static void call() {
    Exception exception = new Exception();
    for(StackTraceElement trace : exception.getStackTrace()){
        System.out.println(trace.getMethodName());
    }
}
```

This will print "call" and "main", methods name in called order (reverse).

Answer (score -5):

This is possible using Reflection API !

```
public class StackTrace {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        StackTrace st = new StackTrace();
        st.func();
    }
    public void func() {
        OtherClass os =new OtherClass();
        os.getStackTrace(this);
    }
}

class OtherClass {
    void getStackTrace(Object obj)  {
        System.out.println(obj.getClass());
    }
}
```

Comment: Does that require me to attach a debugger?

Comment: No not really, this is a technique which JVM uses internally for their purpose. It's really interesting to play around Reflection...

Comment: you can get the caller class - true, but not the arguments

Comment: @Ujjwal, maybe you can extend your answer by copying my code example and make it output the arguments passed to the method that called this method. (It looks like this is not possible)

Comment: This is not possible using reflection alone, as the original code should not be modified (=> you have no place to insert the reflective calls).

Comment: @Ujjwal - your answer is hopelessly vague.  You assert something pretty cool, but don't even give your readers a breadcrumb trail to follow. ... other than googling for "reflection".  Please, add more detail to your answer.