# Java: do methods inherit a JRE super class, like classes inherit Object?

Tags: inheritance, object, methods, java

As far as I know, everything is an object in Java.

I am looking through the java JDK and am experimenting with creating a custom JDK that allows me to perform more debugging operations. For example, I can manipulate every object by changing the Object.java class.

My question is: do methods inherit a class from the JRE as well, so that I can modify this parent to eg. make a method save it's most recently passed arguments?

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you check out one of the existing research VM's like Jikes RVM first. A lot of the issues that come up during VM implementation are discussed and documented there.

Comment: @biziclop, would that allow me to make each method save it's most recently passed arguments to a static variable of the class?

Comment: @Tom No, but if you really want to experiment with modifying the VM, it's a good starting point. Slightly less frustrating than modifying the Sun VM and wondering why nothing works. :)

Comment: @Tom: it is rather complex, because you require a rather complex change to the JVM.

Comment: @Joachim, alright, but does it require the VM to run in debug mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to enhance debugging, you can start with looking at what [JVMTI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html) has to offer. Even before that, see if [JDI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/index.html), a much higher level (and therefore easier to use) API built on top of JVMTI suits your needs.

And although what you're saying doesn't sound possible in itself, a similar effect can be achieved by [instrumentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-frame.html), using a byte code manipulating library, like BCEL.

As for your specific example, if you want to record method invocations and their parameters, simply setting a breakpoint with JDI and then querying the call stack can do the trick.

Comment: "setting a breakpoint with JDI and then querying the call stack can do the trick", this does sound rather complex. Is this possible without modifying the application's source?

Comment: @Tom: that's the idea: JDI/JVM TI can interact with a running JVM without modifying the code running on that JVM. Read the links provided to you, please.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer, does it require the application to run in debug mode?

Comment: @Tom, it requires to start w/ the instrumentation (specified in the command line as agent) which I call it 'debugger settings', although it's not the same as -Xrunjdwp. Basically it's what profilers do

Comment: @bestsss, alright. I'm afraid I cannot start the VM with any special parameters for a couple of reasons. I think I'll have to hack into the JRE files and see what I can do to get the arguments passed to functions.

Answer (score 5):

No, not everything in Java is an object. Methods are not object, primitive values are not objects, references are not objects. Only objects are objects in Java (and arrays).

There are objects that *represent* classes ([`java.lang.Class`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)), methods ([`java.lang.reflect.Method`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html)), constructors ([`java.lang.reflect.Constructor`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html)) and fields ([`java.lang.reflect.Field`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html)). But "representing" something is not the same thing as "being" something.

So no: methods are not objects, they don't inherit from any base class (or "base method").

If you want to interact with the JVM at a low level, then [JVM TI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jvmti/) might be the correct API for you.

Answer (score 1):

Fields, methods, parameters, local variables are not objects in Java.  They have Object which can represent them using reflections, but they are not Objects.

If you want to change the behaviour of a method to trace arguments passed to it you can use code injection. e.g. AspectJ does this and has examples on how to do it.

Comment: I should probably have mentioned that I only have control of the runtime's source (JRE), not of the source of the application itself. Is AspectJ still an option here?

Comment: AspectJ can change the byte code as it is loaded by the JRE. You don't even need direct access to the JARs/classes. I don't think it can change byte code after it is loaded, though it is possible in theory. ;)