# Accessing Java Stack Frame

Tags: java, logging, parameters, stack

Is it possible to access a methods parameters, via stack frame?

I came across this need because of a project I've been working on. In case of an exception, I want to do some logging. If possible, I want to log a method's name and parameters, recursively, until i get to the "upper levels".

Here is a small example:

```
class Parent{

    public int parentMethod(int param1) {
        String param2;
        Child child = new Child();
        (...)some Work(...)
        int ret = child.childMethod(param1, param2);
        (...)some More Work(...)
        return ret;
    }
}


class Child{
    public int childMethod(int param1, String param2) {
        (...) do more stuff (...)
        try {
            (...) this might generate an exception(...)
        }catch(Exception e) {
            (...) log method name and parameters value(...)
        }
    }
}
```

So in this case, I'd like to log something such as:
-childMethod: param1 value, param2 value-
-parentMethod: param1 value-

Comment: What if Child."do more stuff" does `param1++` ?

Comment: Related, perhaps dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943612/java-how-to-get-arguments-passed-to-method-that-called-this-method

Comment: @leonbloy - does it matter ? It's a primitve, and copied by value

Comment: Of course, my point is that, at the moment he wants to log the param1 value that was passed, it will no be available in this scope (perhaps in no scope). You would need to store a copy of all the arguments at the start of the function call if you want to log those values.

Comment: if a parameter is altered, there is no problem in logging it's value after the change has been made.

i'm more focused on the actual logging in a recursive matter that does not make do a specific try catch in every exception possibility. a generic way of handling them that logs the current method parameters and their values, plus the method name.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a fundamental problem. For anything other than primitives, parameters *references* are passed. As such, *a method can change the parameter value that is passed to it*. A simple traversal of the stack won't solve this problem.

I note that your example above uses primitives and immutable objects. However I suspect you need a more generic solution. Perhaps some sort of AOP solution may work, but you're still going to have to copy objects as you call methods (in order to record them) and I forsee a world of grief.

Comment: I used primitives and an object because i needed a generic solution to work with pretty much any kind of object. I do not need it to be "readable and understandable". For example, in objects, there is no problem if i log param1 followed by param1.toString().

Comment: I don't think your issue is with being "readable and understandable". I think it's to do with being "correct and remotely practical".

Comment: Yes, you are quite right. but there is no problem if the parameter value is changed, i'll just log the changed value.

the problem is the actual logging, if it's possible to do like i suggested or not.