# Can an attribute object reach the object for which it is an attribute?

Tags: java, introspection

I'm sorry this question might be odd, but some time ago I used python's introspection, and I was wondering if something like that might be available in Java 1.8.

So let's say I have an object `a` from class `A` in a situation like this

```
class A{ B b; }
class B{ public void f(){} }
```

My question is "can `f()` know about `a`?"

Clearly, it can, if I add a backward link, something like:

```
class A {
    B b;  
    public A() { b = new B(this); } 
}

class B {
    A father; 
    public B(A a){ this.father = a; } 
    public void f(){} 
}
```

But my question is, in the general setting, without the back like to `father` or so, is there any introspection mechanic that could allow `f()` to know about `a`?

Comment: `A a = new A; B b2 = a.b;`  Now what result would you expect?

Comment: Why you need that scenario

Comment: Short answer: no.  Long answer: noooo.

Comment: `A` and `B` have nothing in common. What do you want `f` to know about a class that is not related to a class it is in?

Comment: Even if it's possible, how do you know exactly which of the potentially many instances of `A` holding that instance of `B` is it that you want? There may be many.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: how to get arguments passed to method that called this method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943612/java-how-to-get-arguments-passed-to-method-that-called-this-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wish to access the arguments of a function upper in the call stack. In vanilla Java you can't accomplish that, however you can use some AOP framework, which could maintain a shadow stack, so you can introspect it.

Or you might use inner classes. Inner classes contain a hidden field to the instance of the outer class. It can be accessed with the syntax `OuterClass.this`.

```
class A{
  public class B{ 
    public void f() {
      System.out.println(A.this.aField);
    }    
  }
  String aField;
  B b = new B(); // Passes a hidden `this` parameter
}
```

Comment: this is not the scenario he's talking about- he talks about a case where A and B are completely not related, not a case where B is an inner class in A

Answer (score 1):

If A and B are in the same Package, B knows about the field b inside A is exposed to B. This is possible since you declared the field b inside A with the default visibility which is "private to the package".

Otherwise, if you change A for

```
    class A{ private B b;  
        public A(){ b=new B(this); } 
    }
```

Then you can only access the field B from A using Reflection like this (suppose this code is in a method in B:

```
Field privateStringField = A.class.getDeclaredField("b");
privateStringField.setAccessible(true);

B value = (B) privateStringField.get(this);
```

Now this is a bad idea because you change the name of the field "b" in A, then you broke your code and the compiler won't tell you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. if B is a member of A, it means that A 'knows' B, but not the other way around. you can only access B from A, not the other way around.