# How to get method signature in Spring exception handler?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a global exception handler configured in my environment where i get only the exception stack trace. But now I need to get method signature and an arguments passed to that method where exception has occurred.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You get the signature like this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/421280/476716. You cannot get the arguments: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4943612/476716

Comment: @Aditya Thanks! I tried to achieve this using joinpoint and got what i want but at the same time my STS's performance goes down saying **Performing Remote System Operation**. I am not able to figure out the reason! Is it because of pointcut expression???

Comment: I think you can add logging framework in your project to serve your purpose of debugging.