# Programmatically retrive parameters and values of a method

Tags: java, methods, parameters

it's been quite a few months that i quite Java in favor of Python. Now i'm go back to java to project constraints. 
now, i'm wondering if there's a way to get all the aprameters (with values) of a functions programmatically inside the function itself.

something like this

```
public void foo(String arg1,String arg2, Integer arg3){
... pars = ...getpars();  
}

foo("abc","dfg",123);
```

where `getpars()` should return an `HashMap` with `name,value` pairs.

so from the example should be

```
arg1,"abc"
arg2,"dfg"
arg3,123
```

is there anything like this?

Comment: what is the name and what is value here

Comment: What would you need that for?

Comment: Why would you want to do this within the method itself? There cannot be - at least in your example - suddenly new arguments.

Comment: i need to create an hashmap with key the name of the parameter and value the value of the parameter.

Comment: This looks like a XY problem. What do you **really** need to do?

Comment: @DaDaDom this is a second step, where i want to have dynamic parameters. but in java i can't do that. i want to do this beacuse i don't want to do many lines of code just to create an hashmap for all the functions' parameters

Comment: What is the point of having it? And you can always do it yourself. I am sorry but it is missing the gist.

Comment: Why don't you pass a Map to your function ?

Comment: @EsseTi: exactly: you can't do that in Java, so what's the point? ;-) And as stated in another comment/answer: reflection is the only way to achieve this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237803/can-i-obtain-method-parameter-name-using-java-reflection

Comment: @DaDaDom that if i've 20 methods and i want JUST create a hashmap with <key,value> of parameters i've to do it by hand seems really error prone to me. so i was looking if there is something similar to ** of python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters

Comment: what do you need that maps for in the first place?

Comment: Again, you are missing the point. Please tell what you actually **want to achieve**. Seasoned Java devs do without this just fine. It more and more looks like a design problem.

Comment: @fge i've a function that accepts an hashmap and use it for making an api call. Now, i've functions that uses the api call function. for each of them i've to do the hashmap by hand, parameters by parameters. Plus, some operations (same api call) can have from 1 to 3 parameters, so i've to create 7 different functions to map all the cases). it's only me that found this not really smart approach?

Comment: OK, now this is getting somewhere. What are these "API calls"? Do they use an existing protocol (SOAP, JSON-RPC, other)? Or are they methods from another Java library?

Comment: @fge are methods that i created.yet, it doesn't matter what they do. i  just need to get the parameters as an hasmap or something similar to be flexible. but seems impossibile in java. so i hardcoded everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is impossible. The only thing you can do is to retrieve the list of parameters types of a particular method using `reflection`.

But there is no way to get a map with `name` -> `value` of each argument passed into the method itself.

Comment: It's actually possible using proxy or aspects in Java

Answer (score 2):

You can't get the name of the parameter, because it's no value just a name. If you wanna have the name of the parameter in your Map define a String which matches your parameter name and put it in.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744226/java-reflection-how-to-get-the-name-of-a-variable) similar question. The accepted answer seems to have a solution for this using a third party library.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the names of the parameters dynamically, nor can you find the values in any way other than using the variable names. However, JAVA has the next best thing: variable arguments. If you want to have a dynamic number of arguments, you can declare your method as follows:

```
public void foo(Object... args)
```

When you call the method, you will call it with any number of arguments; `foo(1, 2, "ABC")` and `foo(new File("config.dat"), new Scanner(), 88.5D)` are both valid calls. Inside the function, `args` will be an array containing all of the parameters in order.

Just a few usage tips, though. The method declaration above is, in general, not considered good form. Usually, you can be much more specific. Think hard about whether or not you need all this flexibility, and consider using a few overloaded methods or possibly passing a `HashMap` to the function instead. Very rarely will you actually need to have dynamic parameters in that broad of a sense.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
void foo(String... args) {
    for (String arg: args) { }
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length - 1; i += 2) {
        map.put(args[i], args[i + 1];
    }
}

foo("a", "1", "b", "2");
```

Or use a Map builder, see [builder-for-hashmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7345241/builder-for-hashmap).

Comment: seems intresting, what's the meaning of `...` after `String`?

Comment: @EsseTi it is varargs parameters. Essentially, this is the same as passing a `String[]` as an argument, only nicer to write.

Comment: I also have a similar use case. Did anyone find the solution ?

Comment: @rvkant The OP actually wants a `class Params { int x, double y, String s; }`. With **JAXB** (with annotations like `XmlAttribute`) this then could become XML or JSON, which again as DOM object would work. Not really a compact solution though.

Answer (score 1):

There are some hacky ways of getting the parameters values of an invoked method (But you have to understand that the parameters are unnamed, the best you can do is to get arg0.... argN).

1. Use Proxies
2. Aspect oriented programming (AspectJ, Spring AOP)

Let's consider the 1st approach. Say we want to log parameters before executing the method of some interface MethodParamsInterface, here you go. If you want to use these arguments in your logic - consider to implement them in InvocationHandler (or use EasyMock instead)

```
interface MethodParamsInterface {
    void simpleMethod(int parm1, int parm2);
    void simpleMethod(int parm1, int parm2, int param3);
}

public class MethodParams implements MethodParamsInterface {
    public void simpleMethod(int parm1, int parm2) {
        //business logic to be put there
    }

    public void simpleMethod(int parm1, int parm2, int param3) {
        //business logic to be put there
    }

    public MethodParamsInterface wrappedInstance() throws Exception {
        Class<?> proxyClass = Proxy.getProxyClass(MethodParams.class.getClassLoader(), MethodParamsInterface.class);
        InvocationHandler invocationHandler = new InvocationHandler() {
            @Override
            public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
                Map<String, Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>(args.length);
                for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
                    params.put("arg" + i, args[i]);


                //printing out the parameters:
                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> paramValue : params.entrySet()) {
                    System.out.println(paramValue.getKey() + " : " + paramValue.getValue());
                }

                return MethodParams.this.getClass().getMethod(method.getName(), method.getParameterTypes()).invoke(MethodParams.this, args);
            }
        };
        return (MethodParamsInterface) proxyClass.getConstructor(new Class[]{InvocationHandler.class}).newInstance(invocationHandler);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MethodParams instance = new MethodParams();
        MethodParamsInterface wrapped = instance.wrappedInstance();

        System.out.println("First method call: ");

        wrapped.simpleMethod(10, 20);

        System.out.println("Another method call: ");

        wrapped.simpleMethod(10, 20, 30);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import javassist.util.proxy.MethodFilter;
import javassist.util.proxy.MethodHandler;
import javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

class Test01 {
    public int method01(int i, int j) {
        System.out.println("Original method01");
        return i + j;
    }
}

class ParameterWriter {
    public static <T> T getObject(T inp) throws InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        ProxyFactory factory = new ProxyFactory();
        factory.setSuperclass(inp.getClass());
        factory.setFilter(
                new MethodFilter() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean isHandled(Method method) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
        );
        MethodHandler handler = new MethodHandler() {
            @Override
            public Object invoke(Object self, Method thisMethod, Method proceed, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
                for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println(proceed.getParameters()[i].getName() + ":" + args[i]);
                }
                return proceed.invoke(self, args);
            }
        };
        return (T) factory.create(new Class<?>[0], new Object[0], handler);
    }

}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Test01 test01 = ParameterWriter.getObject(new Test01());
            test01.method01(2, 3);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
arg0:2
arg1:3
Original method01
```